# Not able to get https response from nginx server after installing self signed certificate

Tags: nginx, ssl, php-fpm, timeout, self-signed-certificate

Getting no response from server when connecting with https://
Http is running fine
I have installed self signed certificate and configured properly without errors. I am running nginx with php-fpm. I checked with nginx it is listening on port 443. I tried switching it on 81 too with luck again.

This is my first time with you genius guys so please have mercy and let me know how can I improve my questions

---

### Default nginx config

```
user                            nginx;
pid                             /var/run/nginx.pid;
error_log                       /var/log/nginx/error.log;

worker_processes                auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile            1024;

events {
        use epoll;
        worker_connections 2048;
        multi_accept on;
}

http {
    perl_modules                perl/lib;
    perl_set $uri_lc 'sub {
        my $r = shift;
        my $uri = $r->uri;
        $uri = lc($uri);
        return $uri;
    }';

    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

... 
    upstream fpm_backend {
        server                  127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
    map $scheme $fastcgi_https {
        default                 off;
        https                   on;
    }

    server_tokens               off;
    sendfile                    on;
    tcp_nopush                  on;
    tcp_nodelay                 on;

    client_header_timeout       10m;
    client_body_timeout         10m;
    send_timeout                10m;
    proxy_read_timeout          2m;
    fastcgi_send_timeout        10m;
    fastcgi_read_timeout        10m;
    fastcgi_buffer_size         32k;
    fastcgi_buffers             8 16k;

    client_max_body_size        10M;
    client_header_buffer_size   1k;
    large_client_header_buffers 4 4k;

    output_buffers              4 32k;
    postpone_output             1460;

    keepalive_timeout           65;
    reset_timedout_connection   on;
    types_hash_max_size         2048;

    gzip                        on;
    gzip_disable                'msie6';
    gzip_comp_level             5;
    gzip_min_length             100;
    gzip_buffers                16 8k;
    gzip_types          text/plain application/xml text/css text/js text/xml application/x-javascript text/javascript application/json application/xml+rss application/javascript image/png image/gif image/jpg;

    gzip_vary           on;
    open_file_cache         max=1000 inactive=20s;
    open_file_cache_valid   30s;
    open_file_cache_min_uses    5;
    open_file_cache_errors  off;


    ssl_protocols               TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    include                     /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

---

### included conf out of many others not related

```
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/custom-log.inc;

server {
    listen              80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name     control.xxx.com;

    access_log      /var/log/nginx/control-performance-access1.log performance;
    error_log       /var/log/nginx/control-error.log;

    set $mageCode "kw_en";
    if ($request_uri ~ ^/ar/) {
        set $mageCode 'kw_ar';
    }

    ssl_certificate     /data/csr/customssl/control.xxx.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /data/csr/customssl/control.xxx.com.key;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;
    ssl_protocols       SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
    ssl_ciphers         ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

    location ~* \.(?:png|gif|jpg|jpeg|css|js|swf|ico|txt|xml|bmp|pdf|doc|docx|ppt|pptx|zip)$ {
        expires                 30d;
        add_header              Cache-Control public;
        fastcgi_hide_header     Set-Cookie;
        fastcgi_param           HTTPS on;
        #add_header             Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains;";
    }
    gzip                    on;
    gzip_types              text/plain text/css text/javascript application/x-javascript application/javascript;
    gzip_vary               on;
    #fastcgi_hide_header    Set-Cookie;
    include conf.d/control.xxx.com.options.inc;
    # rewrites configuration
    include conf.d/control.xxx.com.redirects.inc;
    include conf.d/control-blockips.conf;
}
```

---

### control.xxx.com.options.inc

```
#listen          80;
#listen          81 ssl;
root            /data/html/XXX/src;
index           index.php index.html index.htm;
autoindex       off;
expires         off;

location @proxy {
  fastcgi_pass      fpm_backend;
}

location @arhandler {
  rewrite            / /ar/index.php;
}

location ~ (^/(app/|includes/|lib/|pkginfo/|var/|shell/|modules/|report/config.xml|\.|RELEASE_NOTES.txt|LICENSE.+|mage$)|\.(sample|sh)$) {
  deny                    all;
  return                  404;
}

location ~ \.(png|gif|jpg|jpeg|css|js|swf|ico|txt|xml|bmp|pdf|doc|docx|ppt|pptx|zip)$ {
  expires                 1w;
  try_files               $uri $uri/ @proxy;
  access_log              off;
  log_not_found           on;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
  try_files               $uri =404;
  include                 /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_read_timeout    900s;
  fastcgi_connect_timeout 900s;
  fastcgi_pass            fpm_backend;
  fastcgi_keep_conn       on;
  fastcgi_param           HTTPS $fastcgi_https;
  fastcgi_index           index.php;
  fastcgi_param           SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  fastcgi_param           PHP_FLAG "session.auto_start=off \n suhosin.session.cryptua=off";
  fastcgi_param           PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=1024M \n max_execution_time=18000";
  fastcgi_param           MAGE_RUN_CODE $mageCode;
  fastcgi_param           MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
}

location / {
  try_files               $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

location /ar/ {
  try_files               $uri $uri/ @arhandler;
}
```

Comment: It might be listening on `443` but are all the firewalls between you and the server letting `443` through?

Comment: Did you confirm that the port 443 is actually listening? Run the below to show all listening ports: 'netstat -ptnl' Does that return 443?

Comment: yes It did return tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      20835/nginx: master

Comment: Yes Drifter104 no firewalls in between. It use to work before but not now. I also tried creating new certificate but still not able to connect. Also If I am trying wget on the same server with -no-certificate-check I am getting response

Comment: Why have you enabled weak and obsolete SSL protocols and ciphers?

Comment: This I was trying with all the available options hence added those ciphers

Comment: tcpdump: any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 100 bytes
03:56:26.185754 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 106, id 19382, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    IP.PORT> 10.2.0.17.https: Flags [S], cksum 0x7626 (correct), seq 2XYZ, win 8192, options [mss 1410,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
E..4K.@.j..-..{,
....n..~.X\.. .v&..
03:56:27.965627 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 106, id 19384, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    IP.PORT > 10.2.0.17.https: Flags [S], cksum 0x0cbf (correct), seq 3XYZ, win 8192, options [mss 1410,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys for your help.
My IPTables were inactive already.
I tried starting it to check if it works but still no luck.
But when I stopped it again SSL started working.

**Strange but I manage to solve this by simply restarting iptables.**

Hope this helps somebody.

Best,